Broken MacBook laptop screen and can't see login window (or anything) when connecting to a monitor
my MacBook laptop monitor as stopped working. I'm not sure it'll be worth getting it fixed so hoping just to continue using laptop with a separate monitor, via HDMI. The connection works, however I'm just presented with the default background and nothing else.  There's nowhere to enter my login credentials and take me to my Home Screen. I've read that this may be because my MacBook is set up to bypass the login screen, and that this can be changed in my settings, however I can't get to the settings using the monitor, and can't see anything on my laptop due to the screen being broken.
Any tips on how to resolve this very welcome!

Hi. Do you have an idea what version of macOS (or what year you last updated)  and which model and year your Mac it’s? (MacBook Pro 2018 13” or such). Specifically, modern Mac’s don’t boot to the OS and they are running firmware pre boot screen so you can sometimes carefully navigate log in

Thank you!  The link you provided with instructions to navigate logging in without being able to see anything, did the trick.  I was able to get through to the Home Screen and will be able to access my data using the monitor.

Plug an external monitor, power, mouse, and keyboard into the laptop.
Turn the laptop on.
Close the top.
This is clamshell mode.  You should be able to interact with the laptop normally.

Does clamshell mode work in pre boot, FileVault unlock screen that then uses the password to decrypt the OS volume and the OS starts properly?

@bmike Apology for the late ressponse, I had to make time to reboot my MBP and test to be sure. My MBP is FileVault encrypted (not just the default). I started the laptop, then closed it and plugged in peripherals. Clicked the mouse, woke it up, logged into preboot, went all the way to the desktop, all fine.

Thank you so much for the details. No worry on the delay. We often wait a month or year or more here for some clarifications.
